# Can Ubuntu Linux be responsible for low CPU fan RPM?

Tags: 11.10

My system config is as below:

Processor: Core 2 Duo E7500 2.93 GHZ
Motherboard: Asus P5QPL-AM

[image]

I am encountering concurrent system failures; my system suddenly goes off, hard drive stops spinning, but I can see there is still power on the board.

My thought is that this may be due to a kernel issue or over-heating, looking at the numbers above, I have a few questions about what this report tells me;

- Are there any red flags to this reading?
- I don't have chassis fan. Should I install one?
- Is there something else fan or heat related I can do?

Comment: The temperatures seem fairly low for me. You can probably check them out with the BIOS report.

Comment: Is this a laptop, or a desktop?

Comment: Its a desktop. The temps goes high after a few moments to 46 degree C or more without any prior reason.

How I can check BIOS Report ? Do you mean the Manual came with the Motherboard ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using a desktop then first thing need to do is to cleanup the "Heat Sink". This might the reason for High Temperature and random system shutdown.

Linux may be responsible. But in my case this was the problem.